# How to deploy a own REST api code developed in Java to cloud on openshift?

Tags: java, rest, openshift

I have a REST API developed in Java (with MySql, Tomcat/JBOSS EAP), can be packaged in WAR or EAR, i don't know how to deploy the application in Openshift without commiting to GIT(as i feel exposing code through git shows the implementation).

> Actually, i am looking for a free tier Webservices (Other than AWS
>   since AWS ask for a credit card) deployment for my android
>   application/web Application.

I tried looking into so many tutorials, I am not able to understand any of them.

Any help is appreciated.  Even other solution is also fine

**Note:** I checked other questions in stackOverflow, none of them explain the basics or the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Docker images in your OpenShift instance, There are plenty of java Docker examples to explore. You can use Dockerfile file in your project to set application environment and copy already built WAR or EAR. Then build the image using docker cli or The Docker Maven Plugin. Once the image has been built, you can create application using following command

```
$ oc new-app <DOCKER-IMAGE>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply f-society, I am just looking how to make the rest api into docker image and deploy it in openshift, Could you suggest me some of them if it is possible